# Drools 7, event listener to whenever a rule is activated (even if partially matched)

Tags: java, drools

I'm using Drools 7.8 and [DefaultAgendaEventListener](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.CR1/kie-api-javadoc/org/kie/api/event/rule/DefaultAgendaEventListener.html) to handle events.

I'm trying to handle the event when a rule is activated (even if it was partially matched) but have failed so far with every one of the events handled by that class. For example let´s say i have this rule:

```
rule "A"
when
    ConditionA
    ConditionB
    ConditionC
then
    Consequence
end
```

I want to handle the event when any of those 3 conditions (A,B or C) is met, even if the consequence is not fired but it's been hard to find the correct way to do this in Drools docs.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't do that. Drools doesn't create "partial" matches. A rule is either matched or not.

You could try to do something with [named consequences](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_conditional_named_consequences), to kind of create smaller rules, but I've never tried this before.

Hope it helps,