# How to read Drools memory in order to detect partially matched rules

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, rete

I'd like to be able to read Drools memory in such a way that I can detect which condition has matched, even though the rule didn't fire in the end.

Say I have this rule:

```
rule "MyRule"
when
   FirstFact(condition == "str")
   SecondFast(anotherCondition > 30)
then
...
end
```

If I insert only an object "FirstFact" in memory and I call fireAllRules(), the rule will not be fired. But still, I'd like to track down that the first condition of this rule matched.

I understand this is a weird requirement, and it may take some time to develop as it would probably not be straightforward but if there's a way to do it I'm interested.

I was thinking of accessing Drools memory and visit all conditions contained in the Rete tree, but I am not sure if it's a good approach or even possible.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way RETE works, what you are trying to do is not possible. Please read this other Question to get and idea of a possible solution: [Drools 7, event listener to whenever a rule is activated (even if partially matched)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51934097/drools-7-event-listener-to-whenever-a-rule-is-activated-even-if-partially-matc/51935034#51935034)

Hope it helps,

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this is not a convenient solution due to how we write rules in Drools, so I guess we will have to drop this idea completety. Again thanks !